# Why can this not hold in that case?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am looking at an exercise.

Let $S_n=H_0\triangleright H_1 \triangleright \ldots \triangleright H_r=\langle 1\rangle$ and $H_{i-1}/H_i$ be abelian.

Why can the above not hold when each $H_i$ contains all the cycles of length $3$ ?

Comment: Have you tried to see what the subgroup generated by the $3$-cycles looks like?

Comment: Or even simpler: Do all $3$-cycles commute?

Comment: So, when each $H_i$ contains all the cycles of length $3$, are the generated by $3$-cycles? @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: No, they could be larger than that.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you meant to say for $n>4$, and for $H_i$ such that $i\neq r$ since this is possible for $n=3$. To see this take $n=3$ $S_3 \rhd A_3 \rhd \{1\}$. The quotients are $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$ respectively, so the statement holds.

First think about the normal subgroups of $S_n$ when n<5, these should be easy to classify. Then think about the normal subgroups of $S_n$ when $n \geq 5$. Clearly $A_n$ is a normal subgroup of $S_n$ since $[S_n:A_n]=2$. Now it is a commonly known fact that $A_n$ is simple for $n\geq 5$. You can also show that the only proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_n$ is $A_n$ for $n \geq 5$. You can also show that $A_n$ is generated by the set of 3-cycles when $n \geq 3$. To sum it all up:

1. Show $A_n$ is generated by the set of 3-cycles when $n \geq 3$
2. Break it up into 2 cases $n=4$ which you can easily prove by exhaustion and then $n\geq 5$.
3. Show $A_n$ is simple for $n\geq 5$ (this should have been stated or proven in most classes, and if it wasn't it's a rather long proof but doable)
4. Show that the only proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_n$ is $A_n$ for $n\geq 5$.

You should see how it follows from here since $A_n$ is certainly not abelian for $n>3$.